# Perl Devel::REPL re.pl command not found

Tags: perl, cpan

Is there any instruction on installing Devel::Repl? I use cpan Devel::REPL command to have it installed but I cannot launch it using the re.pl command (as suggested https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL)

My cpan command comes from the perl v5.36 installed from homebrew. Is there something I have to do in order to be able to run re.pl? Like adding ~/.cpan to my system $PATH?[image]

Comment: If you install it under a perlbrew managed Perl then you can run only under that Perl -- so `perlbrew use perl-version-with-it;` and then use it ... is that what you are doing and then it fails?

Comment: On my mac it installs the `re.pl` into `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/bin`. Can you check if you have the script in the corresponding directory for 5.36?

Comment: Is it recommended to install perl with perlbrew instead of homebrew directly? I have installed perl using `brew install perl`... 
I have included what I have in my perl bin folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used the `cpan Devel::REPL` command to have it installed but I cannot launch it using the `re.pl` command
> Is there something I have to do in order to be able to run `re.pl` ?

Yes, `re.pl` is installed in the `bin` directory of the perl installation directory. This directory is not automatically added to the search path by homebrew, so you need to add it manually. Add the following line to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.36.0/bin${PATH+:$PATH}"
```

then open a new terminal. You should now be able to type `re.pl` at the prompt to enter the REPL.